# BuiltInDocumentProperties Returns wrong value

Tags: vb.net, windows, ms-word

I want to get the page count for a specified file but it seems to be getting the wrong value for pages, it's outputting the count as 3 when it really is 6. The code being used is the following:

```
Dim myWordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim myWordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    myWordApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    myWordDoc = myWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestInsert.docx")
    MsgBox(myWordDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages").value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the issue described above, what I needed to do is tell it to repaginate after opening the document. Code that worked:

```
Dim myWordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim myWordApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    myWordApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    myWordDoc = myWordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestInsert.docx")
    myWordDoc.Repaginate()
    MsgBox(myWordDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages").value)
```

I'm thinking there's a better solution out there but the above worked for me.